# React Native - Using AsyncStorage to store data in another screen

Tags: javascript, react-native, asyncstorage

I'm trying to store some data in my App using AsyncStorage, but the thing is whenever I submit the data and then navigate to the second screen (where the data should be stored) it is empty.

[navigation button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCYxw.png)

[SendOrder Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QV63t.png)

Here is my code

SendOrder.js

```
import Settlement from './Settlement';

export default class SendOrder extends React.Component {

state = {
    text: '',
    storedValue: '',
}

onSave = async () => {
    const { text } = this.state

    try {
        await AsyncStorage.setItem(key, text);
        Alert.alert('Saved', 'Successful');
    } catch (error) {
        Alert.alert('Error', 'There was an error.')
    }
}

onChange = (text) => {
    this.setState({ text });
}

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <View>
            <Text>- Noter -</Text>
        </View>
        <View>
            <TextInput
                onChangeText = {this.onChange}
                value = { this.state.text }>
            </TextInput>
        </View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress = { this.onSave }>
            <Text style = { styles.addButtonText }> + </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>    
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Settlement.js

```
import SendOrder from './SendOrder';
const key = '@MyApp:key';

export default class Settlement extends React.Component {

    state = {
        text: '',
        storedValue: '',
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.onLoad();
    }

    onLoad = async () => {
        try {
            const storedValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key);
        } catch (error) {
            Alert.alert('Error', 'There was an error.')
        }
    }

  render() {
      const { storedValue, text } = this.state;
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>{storedValue}</Text>
            <View>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress = {this.onLoad}>
                    <Text>Load Data</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the `storedValue` into the state inside `onLoad`, like

```
onLoad = async () => {
    try {
        const storedValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key);
        this.setState({ storedValue });
    } catch (error) {
        Alert.alert('Error', 'There was an error.')
    }
}
```

Hope this will help!

Answer (score 0):

Change this line
" await AsyncStorage.setItem(key, text); " to
" await AsyncStorage.setItem('key', text); "
The name of the key should be string so it should be in single quote.

and 
Change this line
" const storedValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key); " to
" const storedValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem('key'); "
The name of the set key which is called should be string so it should be in single quote.

The keys you are setting is different and the key your are getting is different

Comment: The alert say's Success, but there still data in my second screen, sir.

Comment: Sir in sendOrder.js
Just add 
---** const key = '@MyApp:key'; ** ---
It should work.

Comment: yes sir, but if I remember -- there's an error or bug then the other answer fix it. I want to check your answers both because it works both, but I'm not sure I can do that.

Comment: When you get the set value in a constant, in your case its --- " const storedValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key); " -- just put console.log it and check the set value is correct or not.
Note: This is async process so it may not reflect data instantly.